# How to stop Owl Carousel Autoplay until a video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

in Owl Carousel docs we have an autoplayTimeout option that will change slides automatically.

I have images and videos in my slider at the same time and I need to disable this option when the carousel showing a video tag or change it to my video duration or stop the carousel autoPlay.
I think the owl carousel should have this option by default but I couldn't find it.

this is my setting for the carousel:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:20,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:6000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    animateIn: 'slideInLeft',
    animateOut: 'slideOutRight',
    lazyLoad: true,
    Height:720,
    smartSpeed:100,
    autoplaySpeed:true,
    video:true,
    videoWidth: false,
    videoHeight: false,
    responsive:{
        1000:{
            items:1
        },
        1440:{
            items:1
        },
        2560:{
            items:1
        }
    },
});
```